# Find wget Location Programmatically using PHP?

Tags: php, cron, wget

Is it possible to determine where the `wget` binary is located using PHP? I'm trying to create a softcoded `wget` cron command for my users. I know that in most environments, the `wget` location will already be included in the `PATH` but cron doesn't always share the same environment. To play it safe, I want to use an absolute path like `/usr/bin/wget`.

Is there a constant similar to `PHP_BINDIR`? I cannot assume `wget` will be in the same location as PHP, right? Any other ideas?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can usually use command like `which wget` to get all available executables for wget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's why we have `env`, which is guaranteed to be in `/usr/bin`, so all you have to do is:

```
/usr/bin/env wget [options] [url]
```

And you're good to go, provided the user running the PHP script has the correct permissions to execute `wget`, write the downloaded files to the specified path etc... but that's a different matter

On the other hand, because you've tagged this question with the *crontab* tag, make sure the hashbang at the top of your script uses `env`, too:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
//your script here
```

Then, `wget` will be callable (again: if the environment variables, and permissions check out) plain and simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
exec('wget --help', $output);
var_dump($output);
```

Should yield zomething like:

```
array(172) {
  [0]=>
  string(51) "GNU Wget 1.15, a non-interactive network retriever."
  [1]=>
  string(32) "Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]..."
  [2]=>
  string(0) ""
  [3]=>
  string(72) "Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too."
  ...
```

Tried it on my machine, no problems whatsoever

Answer (score 0):

Is not a php command, but a unix command : `which`.

Example :

```
~ $ which wget
/usr/bin/wget
```